# Is there any IDE support for creating Cordova Plugins?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to develop a plugin for an existing Ionic/Cordova project by following this guide: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

Since I am trying to migrate a simple standalone Android app to a plugin, I have been using Android Studio so far.

When I got to the Java part of the guide which tells me that the entry point of my plugin needs to inherit from `CordovaPlugin`, I began to wonder why Android Studio does not know the necessary dependency. However, I figured that somehow this dependency will be resolved as soon as the plugin code has been added (and thus copied) to the Cordova project.

Nevertheless, I would really like to have my IDE know that I am currently developing a Cordova plugin rather than a standalone application. So here are my questions:

1. Is there any way to tell this either Android Studio or some different IDE?
2. Given that (1) is solvable, does the IDE furthermore decent support for the Ionic part of the development?
3. Furthermore it would be really nice if the IDE could automatically generate (maybe via a script) the scaffolding of a Cordova plugin. Is this somehow possible out of the box?

Since there are tons of IntelliJ plugins I guess that some combination of them should be able to meet my needs. Or is this just wishful thinking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up Cordova plugin project with IDE support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649070/how-to-set-up-cordova-plugin-project-with-ide-support)