# What is the best IDE to develop cordova plugins?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, visual-studio-cordova

In which IDE does cordova plugins are developed mostly? I have tried, vscode, but its more manual configuaration. Can anyone tell me, how to setup plugin development environment in eclipse(tried installing thym but can't install that one too) or android studio (if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

I think Eclipse is much suited for your need.

Check out this answer for the question to learn more, 
[How to set up Cordova plugin project with IDE support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649070/how-to-set-up-cordova-plugin-project-with-ide-support)